# In datasnapshot firebase get one value in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when i am trying to retrive data in android from firebase in my Datasnap object there is all values are retrieved. like this
but i need to get only name value not email. how to retrive only single value from firebase.because i dont need to get email just want to get name.please help me

```
DataSnapshot { key = users, value = {-Kt1RvWFdpJbPalmZ6Mc={name=dd, email=fj@ifgggg.com}, -Kt1RV6lQ-IRRMtY__0s={name=pooja, email=p@gmail.com}, -Kt1RxjkSfkaqkdPepeX={name=mm, email=ssdffff@gnfh.com}, -Kt1Oqj4G_LueUpRanUJ={name=dipak, email=ss@gmail.com}, -Kt1R2cx4p4FoHOgrLBN={name=ss, email=ss@gmail.com}, -Kt1Q2VypwzlUvcP_8z8={name=dhiraj, email=d@gmail.com}} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `users` node is a direct child of the Firebase root, to get only the name, i suggest you using the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
dd
pooja
mm
dipak
ss
dhiraj
```